# Can't establish site to site vpn connection between Cisco 3900 and strongSwan client

Tags: vpn, cisco, site-to-site-vpn, openswan, strongswan

I have website, which displays data, received from gsm modems. So i am trying to connect my website to GSM network provider using vpn.

Provider side there is a Cisco 3900, configured as site to site vpn server and my side i have strongswan installed on debian linux and configured as client.

I am using this guide for client configuration
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/internet-key-exchange-ike/117258-config-l2l.html

### On the GSM network provider side configuration is like this:

- VPN Equipments version: Cisco 3900
- VPN Modules: DES+3DES+AES
- VPN Gateway IP: "VpnGatewayIP"
- Hosts Using VPN: 10.248.64.0/20

### Tunnel Information

**Phase 1 (IKE)**

- Authentication Method: Pre-Shared Key
- Encryption Schema: IKE
- Perfect Forward Secrecy- IKE: DH Group-5
- Encryption Algorithm: AES256
- Hashing Algorithm: SHA1
- Renegotiate IKE SA every: 86400 seconds

**Phase 2 (IPSEC)**

- IPSec: ESP
- Perfect Forward Secrecy-IPSEC: DH Group-5
- Encryption Algorithm IPSec: AES256
- Hashing Algorithm IPSec: SHA1
- Renegotiate IPSec SA every: 3600 seconds
- Aggressive Mode: NOT IN USE

---

This is content of my configuration file
/etc/ipsec.conf

```
config setup
        strictcrlpolicy=no
        charondebug="ike 1, knl 2, cfg 0"

conn %default
     ikelifetime=1440m
     keylife=60m
     rekeymargin=3m
     keyingtries=1
     keyexchange=ikev1
     authby=secret

conn "providerVPN"
     left=MyServerIP
     leftsubnet=MyServerIP/32
     leftid=MyServerIP
     leftfirewall=yes
     right=VpnGatewayIP
     rightsubnet=10.248.64.0/20
     rightid=VpnGatewayIP
     auto=add
     ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536
     esp=aes256-sha1
```

and PSK file /etc/ipsec.secrets

```
MyServerIP VpnGatewayIP : PSK someSecretKey
```

starting client like this

```
/etc/init.d/ipsec start
```

after this ifconfig did not displays any new connection and "ipsec status" gives me the output

```
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none
```

*There is a log from /var/log/daemon.log*

```
Sep  6 17:54:12 gmapfish ipsec[1221]: ipsec starter stopped
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish ipsec[1320]: Starting strongSwan 5.2.1 IPsec [starter]...
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.2.1, Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae, i686)
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL] known interfaces and IP addresses:
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL]   lo
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL]     127.0.0.1
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL]     ::1
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL]   eth0
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL]     "MyServerIP"
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL]     10.19.0.5
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[KNL]     df80::501:a8ef:ef9f:a321
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke updown
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[LIB] unable to load 3 plugin features (3 due to unmet dependencies)
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish charon: 07[KNL] "VpnGatewayIP" is not a local address or the interface is down
Sep  6 17:54:15 gmapfish ipsec[1320]: charon (1348) started after 60 ms
```

Any suggestion what is wrong with my settings?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: [Introduction to strongSwan: Invocation and Maintenance](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IntroductionTostrongSwan#Invocation-and-Maintenance)

Comment: thanks @ecdsa i found how to start with debug  "ipsec start --nofork"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found solution for my problem, it was only configuration issue.

instead of **auto=add** there must be **auto=start** and **esp=aes256-sha1** must be **esp=aes256-sha1-modp1536**

I also added db parameters, but for work it's optional. If you change just this two parameters, it will work.

Final working configuration is like this.

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file                                                                                                                             

# basic configuration                                                                                                                                                           

config setup
    charondebug="ike 4, knl 4, cfg 4, net 4, esp 4, dmn 4,  mgr 4"
        #uniqueids = no                                                                                                                                                         

conn %default
    ikelifetime=1440m
    keylife=60m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    mobike=no
    keyexchange=ikev1
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=200s

conn "providerVPN"
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    aggressive=no
    esp=aes256-sha1-modp1536
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536

    right=VpnGatewayIP
    rightsubnet=10.248.64.0/20
    rightid=VpnGatewayIP
    rightauth=psk

    left=MyServerIP
    leftsubnet=MyServerIP/32
    leftid=MyServerIP
    leftauth=psk

    dpddelay=30s
    dpdaction=hold
    dpdtimeout=120s
    ikelifetime=86400s
    lifetime=86400s
```